# Create local alias for variable

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, variable-definitions, hold

I have a function whose parameters are passed "by reference"

```
Clear[foo]
SetAttributes[foo, HoldFirst]
foo[t_] := t = 10
```

Is it possible to create an alias for `t` within `foo`, so inside the function I can call it something else? I'm looking for something like

```
foo[t_] := With[{k = t}, k = 10]
```

But instead of `With` I want something that keeps `t` unevaluated until inside the function body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undocumented but very useful, it is exactly what `With[{ k := t }, ...]` will do:

```
Clear[foo]
SetAttributes[foo, HoldFirst]
foo[t_] := With[{k := t}, k++ ]

a=5;
foo[a];
a
```

> 6

I use it a lot, read more in:

[What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions? / a / 121173 / Delayed With, Block, and Module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121173/5478)

A more documented approach:

```
ClearAll[foo]
SetAttributes[foo, HoldFirst]
foo[t_] := Module[{k}, Unevaluated[k++] /. k :> t]
```